# changing source script in a page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script src="www.website.com/script.js"></script>
```

i wanna change the url in script tag "src"
I could change it if it had a id or a class but in this case i do not have one 
i just wanna get rid of some ads and pop ups by changing the script of the page with a new script of mine and that's exactly what i am trying to accomplish
any solutions ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Please explain in a lot more detail what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: well i wanna change the url in script tag "src"

Comment: What would that accomplish? By the time you could change it the script would have been loaded. This really sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Do you allow `jquery` to do it?

Comment: Why don't you just use ElementsByTagName?

Comment: i just wanna get rid of some ads and pop ups by changing the script of the page with a new script of mine and that's exactly what i am trying to accomplish